# Parallelization: bad results with threads, good results with processes. Why?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I've got a problem where the parallelization of a C program with threads doesn't really improve speed, whereas parallelization with processes actually does. I don't really understand why, so maybe someone can explain. Here are two programs, both calculate square roots for around 10.000.000 times. First with threads:

```c
//clang  threads.c -Wall -O3 -o with_threads

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define ENTRIES 10485760
#define THREADS 8

int threads_no[THREADS];
int current = 0;

void* squareroot(void* offset) {
  int foo = ENTRIES / current;
  float *a = malloc(sizeof(float)*foo);

  for (int i = 0; i < ENTRIES / current; i++)
    a[i] = i + 1;

  clock_t s0 = clock();

  int i = 0;
  while (i < ENTRIES / current) {
    a[i] = sqrtf(a[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  printf("Thread %d spent %f calculating %d entries\n", *(int*)offset, ((double)(clock() - s0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC), i);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {

  for (int t = 0; t < THREADS; t++)
    threads_no[t] = t;

  while (++current <= THREADS) {
    printf("With %d threads...\n", current);

    pthread_t threads[current];

    for (int t = 0; t < current; t++)
      pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, squareroot, &threads_no[t]);

    for (int t = 0; t < current; t++)
      pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

... and the corresponding code with processes:

```c
//clang  procs.c -Wall -O3 -o with_procs

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ENTRIES 10485760
#define PROCS 8

int procs[PROCS];
int current = 0;

void* squareroot(void* offset) {
  int foo = ENTRIES / current;
  float *a = malloc(sizeof(float)*foo);

  for (int i = 0; i < ENTRIES / current; i++)
    a[i] = i + 1;

  clock_t s0 = clock();

  int i = 0;
  while (i < ENTRIES / current) {
    a[i] = sqrtf(a[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  printf("Process %d spent %f calculating %d entries\n", *(int*)offset, ((double)(clock() - s0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC), i);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {

  for (int t = 0; t < PROCS; t++)
    procs[t] = t;

  printf("Single:\n");
  current = 1;
  squareroot(&procs[0]);
  printf("Parallel:\n");
  current = 0;

  while (++current <= PROCS) {
    printf("Wiht %d procs...\n", current);

    for (int i = 0, pid = 0; i < current; i++) {
      pid = fork();
      if (pid < 0) {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
      } else if (pid == 0) {
        squareroot(&procs[i]);
        exit(0); 
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < current; i++)
      wait(NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On my machine (MacBook Air Core i5 1,7), results for threads are:

```
With 1 threads...
Thread 0 spent 0.030546 calculating 10485760 entries
With 2 threads...
Thread 1 spent 0.032468 calculating 5242880 entries
Thread 0 spent 0.037332 calculating 5242880 entries
With 3 threads...
Thread 0 spent 0.015804 calculating 3495253 entries
Thread 1 spent 0.026870 calculating 3495253 entries
Thread 2 spent 0.029845 calculating 3495253 entries
With 4 threads...
Thread 3 spent 0.037240 calculating 2621440 entries
Thread 0 spent 0.052195 calculating 2621440 entries
Thread 1 spent 0.056285 calculating 2621440 entries
Thread 2 spent 0.054233 calculating 2621440 entries
With 5 threads...
Thread 1 spent 0.026005 calculating 2097152 entries
Thread 3 spent 0.031361 calculating 2097152 entries
Thread 4 spent 0.041360 calculating 2097152 entries
Thread 2 spent 0.054898 calculating 2097152 entries
Thread 0 spent 0.034579 calculating 2097152 entries
With 6 threads...
Thread 2 spent 0.026277 calculating 1747626 entries
Thread 4 spent 0.029041 calculating 1747626 entries
Thread 1 spent 0.028271 calculating 1747626 entries
Thread 3 spent 0.018770 calculating 1747626 entries
Thread 5 spent 0.043817 calculating 1747626 entries
Thread 0 spent 0.019002 calculating 1747626 entries
With 7 threads...
Thread 0 spent 0.022857 calculating 1497965 entries
Thread 3 spent 0.050611 calculating 1497965 entries
Thread 5 spent 0.015109 calculating 1497965 entries
Thread 4 spent 0.028377 calculating 1497965 entries
Thread 1 spent 0.043619 calculating 1497965 entries
Thread 2 spent 0.071591 calculating 1497965 entries
Thread 6 spent 0.022199 calculating 1497965 entries
With 8 threads...
Thread 2 spent 0.039933 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 5 spent 0.021614 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 7 spent 0.062763 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 3 spent 0.041014 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 0 spent 0.033286 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 6 spent 0.044050 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 4 spent 0.082030 calculating 1310720 entries
Thread 1 spent 0.016579 calculating 1310720 entries
```

and for processes:

```
Single:
Process 0 spent 0.030531 calculating 10485760 entries
Parallel:
Wiht 1 procs...
Process 0 spent 0.030548 calculating 10485760 entries
Wiht 2 procs...
Process 0 spent 0.015946 calculating 5242880 entries
Process 1 spent 0.015995 calculating 5242880 entries
Wiht 3 procs...
Process 1 spent 0.012040 calculating 3495253 entries
Process 0 spent 0.014993 calculating 3495253 entries
Process 2 spent 0.016536 calculating 3495253 entries
Wiht 4 procs...
Process 1 spent 0.009256 calculating 2621440 entries
Process 2 spent 0.011725 calculating 2621440 entries
Process 0 spent 0.008604 calculating 2621440 entries
Process 3 spent 0.011057 calculating 2621440 entries
Wiht 5 procs...
Process 0 spent 0.007498 calculating 2097152 entries
Process 1 spent 0.008804 calculating 2097152 entries
Process 4 spent 0.008814 calculating 2097152 entries
Process 3 spent 0.010208 calculating 2097152 entries
Process 2 spent 0.009060 calculating 2097152 entries
Wiht 6 procs...
Process 1 spent 0.005633 calculating 1747626 entries
Process 2 spent 0.005553 calculating 1747626 entries
Process 0 spent 0.005950 calculating 1747626 entries
Process 4 spent 0.005977 calculating 1747626 entries
Process 3 spent 0.009157 calculating 1747626 entries
Process 5 spent 0.009563 calculating 1747626 entries
Wiht 7 procs...
Process 4 spent 0.005060 calculating 1497965 entries
Process 0 spent 0.005710 calculating 1497965 entries
Process 1 spent 0.004703 calculating 1497965 entries
Process 3 spent 0.005091 calculating 1497965 entries
Process 6 spent 0.007243 calculating 1497965 entries
Process 5 spent 0.004760 calculating 1497965 entries
Process 2 spent 0.005729 calculating 1497965 entries
Wiht 8 procs...
Process 0 spent 0.005995 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 1 spent 0.004285 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 2 spent 0.006809 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 7 spent 0.005404 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 3 spent 0.005978 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 5 spent 0.004108 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 6 spent 0.005336 calculating 1310720 entries
Process 4 spent 0.005409 calculating 1310720 entries
```

With threads, there's always at least one thread taking as long as a single run, so no improvement. Processes seem to be far better balanced. I'm not using any synchronization primitives for threads, as they are not necessary. Can someone explain why they are so different? I searched Google for quite a long time with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Measuring time with `gettimeofday/2` after taking the comments into account, the thread implementation actually seems correct. For reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define ENTRIES 10485760
#define THREADS 8

int threads_no[THREADS];
int current = 0;

void* squareroot(void* offset) {
  int foo = ENTRIES / current;
  float *a = malloc(sizeof(float)*foo);

  for (int i = 0; i < ENTRIES / current; i++)
    a[i] = i + 1;

  clock_t s0 = clock();

  int i = 0;
  while (i < ENTRIES / current) {
    a[i] = sqrtf(a[i]);
    ++i;
  }
  // printf("Thread %d spent %f calculating %d entries\n", *(int*)offset, ((double)(clock() - s0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC), i);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {

  for (int t = 0; t < THREADS; t++)
    threads_no[t] = t;

  struct timeval t1, t2;
  double elapsedTime;

  // start timer


  while (++current <= THREADS) {
    printf("With %d threads... ", current);
    gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
    pthread_t threads[current];

    for (int t = 0; t < current; t++)
      pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, squareroot, &threads_no[t]);

    for (int t = 0; t < current; t++)
      pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
    elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
    elapsedTime += (t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
    printf("%f\n", elapsedTime);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Best,
Martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clock` measures process time, not thread time. It is useless for measuring performance of individual threads.

Comment: Thanks, major insight. What is a reliable method of measuring performance regardless of whether I split work across threads or processes?

Comment: I know one for Linux (`man clock_gettime`) but not for Mac OS X.

Comment: I've got access to a linux system, so i'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think it probably has to do with the `clock()` call.
In my system (no -O3 and with 8 times more data) I got the following:

```
With 1 threads...
Thread 0 spent 2.390000 calculating 83886080 entries
With 2 threads...
Thread 0 spent 2.390000 calculating 41943040 entries
Thread 1 spent 2.380000 calculating 41943040 entries
With 3 threads...
Thread 0 spent 2.380000 calculating 27962026 entries
Thread 1 spent 2.370000 calculating 27962026 entries
Thread 2 spent 2.370000 calculating 27962026 entries
With 4 threads...
Thread 0 spent 2.370000 calculating 20971520 entries
Thread 2 spent 2.380000 calculating 20971520 entries
Thread 3 spent 2.260000 calculating 20971520 entries
...
With 7 threads...
Thread 1 spent 2.370000 calculating 11983725 entries
Thread 4 spent 2.340000 calculating 11983725 entries
Thread 0 spent 2.340000 calculating 11983725 entries
Thread 6 spent 2.340000 calculating 11983725 entries
....
With 8 threads...
Thread 1 spent 2.320000 calculating 10485760 entries
Thread 0 spent 2.330000 calculating 10485760 entries
Thread 5 spent 2.350000 calculating 10485760 entries
....
Thread 3 spent 2.060000 calculating 10485760 entries
```

Now, looking at `clock()` man page, it says:

```
On several other implementations, the value returned by clock() also includes
the times of any children whose status has been collected via wait(2) (or 
another wait-type call).
Linux does not include the times of waited-for children in the value returned by
clock(). The times(2) function, which explicitly returns (separate) information 
about the caller and its children, may be preferable.
```

So maybe it is a timing related issue?

P.S. in my test, the speed up was really clear.

Comment: Thanks for doing the benchmark! Same answer as from n.m. I will look into how I can measure timing among threads appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Did you really intend for 'current' to be global? You're mutating it while other threads are using it.

Comment: This is only code for debugging the different behaviour of threads and processes. However, current is only modified before the threads are spawned and after they are created, thus it should have no effect.

Comment: Mm, with some reasonable assumptions about barrier semantics of the pthread functions, yeah. I think I misread due to reading on my phone earlier.